# Why does my picture appear before the text?

Tags: c++, ms-word

I am using Visual C++ to automate Word, in the following code I try to insert text followed by a picture:

```
// OLEParagraphs is an object of COLEParagraphs
COLEParagraph LastParagraph = OLEParagraphs.get_Last();
COLERange LastParagraphRange = LastParagraph.get_Range();
COLEInlineShapes InlineShapes = LastParagraph.get_InlineShapes();

LastParagraphRange.put_Text(_T(“See picture below:”));
InlineShapes.AddPicture(strPicFileName, COleVariant(0l), COleVariant(1l), DOCX_VARIANT_OPTIONAL);
```

However, after executing the code, I find the text is always put AFTER the picture, not BEFORE the picture, why?

Thanks

Comment: That is a *very* obscure library you are using.  Congrats, you are the only Google hit for DOCX_VARIANT_OPTIONAL.  Smells like something OpenXml based, hard to guess.  The interop function requires 4 extra arguments to place the picture relative to the page.  Page, not paragraph.  Enlighten us about this library.

Comment: This has to do with how Word defines and works with a RANGE object. Look for the COLLAPSE method in the library you're using. You want the wdCollapseEnd type for the Direction parameter becaûse you need to redefine the Range to be at the end of the text you've inserted into the Range. (Note: if you'd try to insert more text it would REPLACE the text you already assigned to the Range if you didn't collapse the Range, first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the description of the range parameter (the last for which you provide DOCX_VARIANT_OPTIONAL):

```
Optional Object. The location where the picture will be placed in the text. If the range isn't collapsed, the picture replaces the range; otherwise, the picture is inserted. If this argument is omitted, the picture is placed automatically.
```

I would guess this is something to do with "automatic placement". Try inserting a placeholder range before the text and specifying that as the location.